# Trying to use Python PIL ImageDraw.textbbox because of textsize deprecation but I am getting errors

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have zero issues writing text with textsize but I don't understand what I am doing wrong with textbbox. I am getting error:

> File
> "c:\Users\email\OneDrive\Personal\Documents\Code\Python\TestPatternGenerator\test.py",
> line 14, in 
> textwidth, textheight = draw.textbbox("text", font=font)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: ImageDraw.textbbox() missing 1 required positional
> argument: 'text'

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

# Create an image object
img = Image.new("RGB", (400, 400), (255, 255, 255))

# Create a draw object
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

# Define the font to be used for the text
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 36)

# Get the text bounding box
text = "Hello World!"
textwidth, textheight = draw.textbbox(text, font=font)

# Calculate the position for the text
x = (img.width - textwidth) / 2
y = (img.height - textheight) / 2

# Draw the text on the image
draw.text((x, y), text, (0, 0, 0), font=font)

# Save the image
img.save("hello_world.png")
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message states that you are missing an argument in this line:

```
textwidth, textheight = draw.textbbox(text, font=font)
```

If you look up the [documentation for textbbox](https://pc-pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ImageDraw/ImageDraw_textbbox.html), you see that the first argument should be `xy`, the anchor coordinates of the text. This is missing in your line of code.

Solution: you should calculate the position first, and then use that in your call to `bbox`. Alternatively, in your case, you only want to know the size of the bounding box at that point of the code, so you can use `(0, 0)` as a position.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you! I find it very difficult to turn documentation into code but show me a working code sample and I'll understand how to use it right away.

Comment: `textbbox` returns the bounding box (left, top, right, bottom) though so it's more `text_left, text_top, text_right, text_bottom = draw.textbbox(text, font=font)` followed by `textwidth, textheight = (text_right - text_left, text_bottom - text_top)`.